# How to make a search in AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to make a research in AJAX but it's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Code in my View with the DOM load :

```
$(function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
        });
        templateCategories = Handlebars.compile($('#CategoriesTemplate').html());
        templateAnimes = Handlebars.compile($('#AnimesTemplate').html());
        templatePerso = Handlebars.compile($('#PersoTemplate').html());

        $.getJSON("Animes/GetCategories", null, function (data) {
            var result = templateCategories(data);

            $('#CategoriesOutput').html(result);

            //fonctionne pas ça chie ma vie :(
            $("#btn_rech").on("click", function () {
                $.getJSON("Animes/GetAnimesOrdered", { search: $("#rech").val() }, function (data) {
                    var output = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d; i++) {
                        output += "<div id='AnimesOutput' onclick='GetPersonnages(\"" + data.d[i] + "\")'>" + data.d[i] + "</div>";
                    }
                    $("#AnimesOutput").html(output);
                    console.log($("#rech").val());
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Maybe it can help If I add this code too :

```
<div id="Rech">
    Rechercher un anime en particulier? : <input type="text" id="rech" placeholder="anime" />
    <input type="button" id="btn_rech" value="Rechercher" />
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Catégories</h3>

    <div id="CategoriesOutput">

    </div>

    <h3>Animes</h3>

    <div id="AnimesOutput">

    </div>

    <h3>Personnages</h3>

    <div id="PersoOutput">

    </div>
</div>
<script id="CategoriesTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each}}
    <h3 class="categories" onclick="GetAnimes({{CategoryID}})">{{CategoryNom}}</h3>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="AnimesTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each}}
    <h3 class="animes" onclick="GetPersonnages({{AnimeID}})">{{AnimeNom}}</h3>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="PersoTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each}}
    <h3 class="perso">{{PersonnageNom}}</h3>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Method in my Controller :

```
public JsonResult GetAnimesOrdered(string search)
    {
        var animeTriees = db.Animes.Where(s => s.AnimeNom.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();

        return Json(animeTriees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I got an error : GET http://localhost:10760/Animes/GetAnimesOrdered?search=dragon 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here's a printscreen :

[image]

Comment: What is your controller name?? You are sure that it is Animes?

Comment: Yes the name of my controller is Animes, and it's the one that I'm using form this application

Comment: Share the web routing.cs from your projcet please

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper Annotation set on the action?

I guess it should be something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAnimesOrdered(string search)
{
    var animeTriees = db.Animes.Where(s => s.AnimeNom.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();

    return Json(animeTriees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

(This was meant as a comment more than an answer, but I'm too low on rep)

Comment: It's not working even If I try your method, I have again the 500 internal server error in the console. If put break points and I see the results in the program, but I don't see the result when I launch the application

Comment: Can you please share the response of the 500 error?
You can find it in the network tab if you click the failed request and go into the response tab

Comment: Here's the error message : GET http://localhost:10760/Animes/GetAnimesOrdered?search=dragon 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Yes, in the console, but under the network tab you can see what the actual error might be. If you can't get anymore info from the network tab, a viable option would be to download Fiddler2 (great tool to see the communication between client and server)

Comment: If I go in the network tab, I see that the error is in my JQuery script that I've download, and when I click on the link, I saw anonymous function and the line is this one :  $.getJSON("Animes/GetAnimesOrdered", { search: $("#rech").val() }, function (data) {

Comment: Ok then. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your method and see what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82614/discussion-between-aloveforcoffee-and-joel-gobeil).

Comment: Yes I added some, I see what I wrote in my textbox, the count of the number of items who contains these characters, but the contain of the """"<div>" doesn't change